# Environment variables not being loaded

Tags: typescript, npm, mysql2

I'm trying to create a mysql2 connection on nodejs but It's not loading my variables

this is how it's set up the function

```
const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  connectionLimit: 10,
});

export async function dbConnection() {
  if (!process.env.DB_HOST || !process.env.DB_USER || !process.env.DB_PASSWORD || !process.env.DB_NAME) {
    throw new Error('Missing environment variables for database connection');
  }
  console.log(process.env.DB_HOST, process.env.DB_HOST, process.env.DB_USER, process.env.DB_PASSWORD, process.env.DB_NAME);
  const connection = await pool.getConnection();
  return connection;
}
```

I already checked packages and reinstalling node package, dotenv is configured as well.

Comment: How did you configure dotenv?

Comment: How exactly are you setting those environment variables?